# Excluding Data from SQL Results based on DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query built:  My problem is that if I get a date that is past today's date in the policy_exp_date I need to exclude everything that is insplans or clientplans related and still return everything else specified.

To summarize: If Policy_Exp_DATE > TODAY then pull * else exclude insplans.* or clientplans.*

```
select clients.CLIENT_ID_1 as SourceMRN,
 '' AS HMOMEMBER,
 '' as IDXMRN,
replace (clients.CLIENT_ID_2,'-','') as PatientSSN,
clients.LAST_NAME as LASTNAME,
clients.FIRST_NAME as FIRSTNAME,
clients.MIDDLE_NAME as MIDDLENAME,
 '' as PTMothersMaiden,
convert (varchar,clients.BIRTH_DATE,112) as DOB, 
clients.sex as GENDER,
 '' as PTNICKNAME,
 '' as RACE,
clients.ADDRESS_1,
clients.ADDRESS_2,
clients.CITY,
clients.STATE,
clients.ZIP_CODE,
 '' as FLD18,
 '' as FLD19,
 clients.PHONE_1 as PTHOMEPHONE,
 '' as PTCELL,
 '' as PTEMAIL,
 '' as PTDAYPHONE, 
 (case WHEN [CLIENTS].LANGUAGE_ID LIKE '0' THEN 'ENGLISH' 
 when [clients].LANGUAGE_ID like '1' then 'SPANISH' END) as LANGUAGE,
 '' as MaritalStatus,
 '' as Religion,
 '' as Ethnicity,
 '' as PtExpDate,
 '' as PtExpIndex,
 '' as LASTUPDATEDATE,
 convert (varchar,clientlog.FNDATE,112) as LASTUPDATEDATE,
 '' as PCPNAME,
 '' as VIP,
 '' as FLD33,
 '' as PREFCONTACT,
 '' as FLD35,
 '' as GUARANTORNAME,
 '' AS GUARADDRESS1,
 '' AS GUARADDRESS2,
 '' AS GUARCITY,
 '' AS GUARSTATE,
 '' AS GUARZIP,
 '' AS GUARHOMEPHONE,
 '' AS GUARWORKPHONE,
 '' AS GUARRELATIONSHIP,
 '' as GUARSSN,
 '' as GUAREMPNAME,
 '' as FLD47,
 '' AS GUAREMPADDRESS1,
 '' as GUAREMPADDRESS2,
 '' as GUAREMPCITY,
 '' AS GUAREMPSTATE,
 '' AS GUAREMPZIP,
 '' AS GUAREMPPHONE,
 '' AS GUAREMPSTATUS,
 '' AS FLD55,
 '' AS FLD56,
 '' AS FLD57,
 '' AS FLD58,
 '' AS FLD59,
 '' AS FLD60,
 '' AS FLD61,
 '' AS FLD62,
 '' AS FLD63,
 '' AS FLD64,
 '' AS FLD65,
 insplans.DESCRIPTION_UPPER AS FINANCIAL_CLASS,
 '' as PAYERID#,
 insplans.DESCRIPTION_UPPER as PAYERNAME,
 '' as PAYERADDRESS2,
 '' AS PAYERCITY,
 '' AS PAYERSTATE,
 '' AS PAYERZIP,
 '' AS PAYERCONTACTNBR,
 clientplans.GROUP_NO AS GROUPNUMBER,
 convert (varchar,clientplans.START_DATE,112) as POLICY_EFF_DATE,
 convert (varchar,clientplans.END_DATE,112) as POLICY_EXP_DATE,
 clientplans.SEQUENCE_NUM,
(clients.LAST_NAME +'^' + clients.FIRST_NAME)as INSURED_NAME,
 '' as INSURED_DOB,
 '' AS INSURED_ADD1,
 '' AS INSURED_ADD2,
 '' AS INSURED_CITY,
 '' AS INSURED_STATE,
 '' AS INSURED_ZIP,
 '' AS INSURED_PLAN_NBR,
 clientplans.POLICY_NO AS POLICY_NBR,
 '' AS INSURED_GENDER,
 '' AS INSURED_HOMEPHONE,
 '' AS INSURED_EMP_NAME,
 '' AS INSURED_RELATION,
 '' AS ACCIDENT_DATE,
 '' AS ACCIDENT_CODE,
 '' AS ACCIDENT_STATE,
 '' AS FLD94,
 '' AS CLINICAL_REMINDER,
 '' AS APPT_REMINDER,
 '' AS INS_INST,
 '' AS SET_ID,
 '' AS COPAY,
 'CC' AS SOURCE_PREFIX
 FROM project.dbo.CLIENTS
 join CLIENTPLANS
    on clients.RECORD_ID = clientplans.CLIENT_ID
 join INSPLANS
    on insplans.RECORD_ID = clientplans.PLAN_ID
 join (SELECT MAX(fndate) FNDATE,client_id
 from CLIENTLOG
 group by CLIENT_ID)CLIENTLOG
 on clientlog.CLIENT_ID = clients.RECORD_ID
 where clients.RECORD_ID = clientplans.CLIENT_ID
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are *not* the same thing.

Comment: Why all the empty strings?

Comment: The empty strings are necessary as there are interface requirements for the file that these results will ultimately be used for.

Comment: Please add more details. and try to remove irrelevant code from the question. Check [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Would something like work?

```
FROM project.dbo.CLIENTS
 join (SELECT MAX(fndate) FNDATE,client_id
        from CLIENTLOG
        group by CLIENT_ID)CLIENTLOG
    on clientlog.CLIENT_ID = clients.RECORD_ID
 Left Outer join CLIENTPLANS
    on clients.RECORD_ID = clientplans.CLIENT_ID
      And clientplans.END_DATE > GetDate()
 Left Outer join INSPLANS
    on clientplans.PLAN_ID = insplans.RECORD_ID
```

Also make sure to remove the where clause or you will be removing a lot of the records.